# Can't set date on Debian Amazon EC2 isntance

Tags: linux, debian, amazon-ec2, time

I don't know if the fact that the server is an Amazon EC2 instance makes any difference, but I thought I should mention it.

I'm trying to set the time to an incorrect time for testing reasons.

The server is running Debian 5.0.2

When I try to set the time, it immediately reverts back.

```
# date -s "2125"
Fri May 13 21:25:00 IST 2011
# date
Fri May 13 12:37:49 IST 2011
```

If I run `# dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` (found on [Debian User Forums](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=43114)) and change the timezone there to a different time zone, the value returned from `# date` is still exactly as before.

I'm a bit confused as to why there are two programs that seem to change different time values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting following variable

`# echo 1 > /proc/sys/xen/independent_wallclock`

Comment: even with sudo I get "-bash: /proc/sys/xen/independent_wallclock: Permission denied"

Comment: I had to set it with `sysctl -w xen.independent_wallclock=1`

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist on amazon linux :(

Answer (score 0):

Xen sets the system clock at regular intervals, from the host/hypervisor's clock.

Another question addressed this phenomenon: [Do I need to run ntpd in my EC2 instance?](https://serverfault.com/questions/100978/do-i-need-to-run-ntpd-in-my-ec2-instance)