# Windows 7 as NTP Time Server

Tags: windows-7, ntp

Trying to get Windows 7 box to act as an NTP Time Server for linux clients

From [here](http://windows7forums.com/tweaks-guides-howto/43921-windows-7-authoritative-time-server.html):

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config\ 
>   In the right pane, right-click AnnounceFlags, and then click Modify. 
>   In the Edit DWORD Value dialog box, under Value data, type 5, and then
>   click OK.  Enable NTPServer.  Locate and then click the following
>   registry subkey: 
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpServer\
>   In the right pane, right-click Enabled, and then click Modify.  In the
>   Edit DWORD Value dialog box, type 1 under Value data, and then click
>   OK.
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\VMICTimeProvider\
>   In the right pane, right-click Enabled, and then click Modify In the
>   Edit DWORD Value dialog box, type 0 under Value data, and then click
>   OK Exit Registry Editor.  At the command prompt, type the following
>   command to restart the Windows Time service, and then press ENTER: 
>   net stop w32time && net start w32time

Turned off firewall on Win7 box.

**EDIT 2 - This is working**

[image]
Using Meinberg NTPD

**EDIT**

[image]

Just after I posted I noticed the service had stopped... still the time doesn't sync on the linux box

[image]

however looking at the traffic on Microsoft Network Monitor I see that port 123 is unreachable.

Maybe I should try using NetTime? http://www.timesynctool.com/

Comment: Why not just put [ISC's NTPd](http://www.meinberg.de/english/sw/ntp.htm) on the computer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Microsoft, "[the Windows Time service is not an exact implementation of the Network Time Protocol (NTP)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773013%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)." It works well enough as a time server for other Windows machines, but it should *not* be used as a time server for Linux clients with an expectation that time will be kept in sync precisely. The deficiencies of W32Time are laid out in Microsoft's [KB939322](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939322/en-us) article:

> We do not guarantee and we do not support the accuracy of the W32Time service between
>   nodes on a network. The W32Time service is not a full-featured NTP solution that meets 
>   time-sensitive application needs. The W32Time service is primarily designed to do the 
>   following:
>
> - Make the Kerberos version 5 authentication protocol work.
> - Provide loose sync time for client computers.

Kerberos version 5 requires computers to be synchronized *within 5 minutes* -- a very low standard of accuracy! W32Time may get you within a few seconds most of the time, but Microsoft absolutely *does not guarantee* this level of performance.

The solution is to use a real NTP server, which is to say, use `ntpd`. Normally, your time server would be one of your Linux machines, but [Windows ports of ntpd](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Main/ExternalTimeRelatedLinks#Microsoft_Windows) are available if needed.

Comment: Thanks to you and ChrisS.  I switched over to Meinberg's NTPd.  http://www.thetimenow.com/cst/central_standard_time (edited) this helped to give exact time.  As did setting my Win7 box to talk to localhost for its own clock (NTPd is talking to some authoritative NTP server).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fm2ZU.png - here's a screenshot showing a linux box and a Windows box. We point all our linux boxen at our AD domain name (i.e. all DCs) for NTP. As you can see their time is pretty well synced. Can you elaborate on what the issues are with doing this? Just curious to know if I'm sitting on a ticking timebomb here. We've been doing this for 3+ years already.

Comment: Added more detail above. Not a time bomb, but W32Time's minor inaccuracies can be *very* frustrating when comparing syslog/eventlog data for related events between different hosts on a Windows network.

Comment: I've had a lot of problems trying to syncronise Linux and Windows servers.  Do you know if an Amazon EC2 Linux server would make a suitable NTP server for a domain?  Or does the EC2 hypervisor override the clock?

Comment: I'm still not seeing the need to point my linux boxes elsewhere. They're synced to within 1 second accuracy, where is the problem?

Comment: @GraemeDonaldson In your case, the [Bert Lance Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_it_ain%27t_broke,_don%27t_fix_it#.22If_it_ain.27t_broke.2C_don.27t_fix_it..22) may prevail.

Comment: @paradroid Yes, it would work. See also: [Do I need to run ntpd in my EC2 instance?](http://serverfault.com/questions/100978/do-i-need-to-run-ntpd-in-my-ec2-instance/241705#241705)

Answer (score -1):

Well Microsoft W32Time Service will sync your local clock with any of NTP server. First Make your Windows 7 machine to sync with times.microsoft.com or pool.ntp.org and then with enable NTP server from Computer Management -> Group Policy Editor.

All steps are as below :

- Open the Group Policy Editor
- Click Computer Configuration , click Administrative Templates , click
  System , and then click Windows Time Service .
- Click Time Providers , double-click Enable Windows NTP Server in the
  right pane, click the Enabled button, and then click OK .
- From the Group Policy Object Editor menu, click File , and then click
  Exit.

Reference from :

http://javadotnet.in/2013/01/16/create-your-own-ntp-server-for-lan-with-windows-2008-windows-7/

Comment: this is not an answer that relates to a time server, it's a time client answer.