# EC2 Instance time and hardware clock

Tags: amazon-ec2, arch-linux, time

I have set up an EC2 instance, running ArchLinux, for use as a server. Doing what I always do when installing Arch, I try to fix the time by using:

```
# hwclock --systohc --utc
```

This does not work, and I get from the system:

```
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
hwclock: Use the --debug option to see the details of our search for an access method.
```

I am pretty sure this has to do with the virtualised nature of EC2 instances.

If anyone could educate me as to what can fix this, I would be grateful.
On a different note, what are the implications if I leave the time issue as is and not do anything? Will something malfunction on the server? Will the time go crazy?

Comment: Are amazon EC2 instances not set wit the HW clock set to utc? What exactly is the 'time issue' that you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/100978/do-i-need-to-run-ntpd-in-my-ec2-instance) may be definitely helpful for you. I can see a several seconds drift on my instances (RHEL6, micro instances) as well where I don't run NTP server. EC2 instances  used to synchronize their clocks with hypervisor clock.  Available clock sources are visible in

```
/sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
```

The one which is used is in

```
/sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
```

So if you want more accurate time configure `NTP` server or run `ntpdate` client regularly via cron.